# Passing computed values with RIA Services

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I'm trying to figure out the a way to get extra data to be passed with the entities returned from a RIA domain service.

For example, let's say I want to display a DataGrid for "Orders" and include a column for the total items in an order.

```
Order Num.  |  Cust. Name |  *No. of Items Ordered*
4545        |  John       |   4    
1234        |  Mike       |   7
```

On the server side, with a Linq query, I could do:

```
var query = 
    from o in entities.Orders
    select new OrderWithItemCount { Order = o, ItemCount = o.Items.Count() };
```

... and this will retrieve my orders along with the Items counts all in one go.

The problem is, I can't find anyway to propagate these results thru a domain service to the Silverlight client.  I suppose I could use a standard WCF service, but what's the fun in that?

**Update**

**What turned out to be the actual problem...**

I had at one point actually already tried the "**Easy way**" that Nissan Fan and Florian Lim point out. When I tried it, I wasn't getting all my data. (I also need to include the customer `Person` in the query to get their name.) It turns out that what I thought was a limitation of RIA Services was actually a limitation of EF 4.0, in that saying `entities.Orders.Include("Customer")` won't work if you select a new type that isn't an `Order`. The work around is to explicitly select `o.Customer` in your select statement, and EF will automatically wire the selected Person into the assiocated property on `Order`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Easy way:**

Just add extra fields to your Order class (could be done in a partial class) and populate that in your DomainService.

**Complicated but more flexible way:**

Define OrderWithItemCount as an entity (needs to have a [Key] attribute), then transfer that.

```
public class OrderWithItemCount
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // You need this, so that the DomainContext on the client can put them back together.
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    [Include]
    [Association("OrderReference", "OrderId", "Id")]
    public Order Order { get; set; }

    public int ItemCount { get; set; }

    public Person Customer { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<OrderWithItemCount> GetOrdersWithItemCount()
{
    var query = from o in entities.Orders
                select new OrderWithItemCount
                {
                    OrderId = o.Id,
                    Order = o,
                    ItemCount = o.Items.Count,
                    Customer = o.Customer, // Makes sure EF also includes the Customer association.
                };
    return query;
}
```

There may be minor errors in the code, since I cannot test this at the moment, but I recently implemented something similar.

Comment: I was not aware you could define a new entity and use it this way, thanks!

Comment: I'm going to submit an edit for the code, will be happy to mark as answer.

Comment: Creating a whole new entity to achieve this is certainly and option, but you would be at the intended destination quicker by simply adding a property to the partial class created by the Domain Service proxy or by adding it as a partial class to your LINQ to SQL/EF.  See below.

Comment: @Nissan Fan: Agreed, in fact that's the way I went with my real code.  I marked Florian's answer as correct simply because he posted a few minutes before you did and also included the info about creating a new entity, which may come in handy in a more complex situation.  Your answer is also correct and much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using LINQ to SQL to produce your Domain Service you could simply go into the partial class for Orders and add a Property called NumberOfOrders which returns an Int representing the count.  This property would carry through to the client without issue.

```
internal sealed class OrderMetadata
        {
// Metadata classes are not meant to be instantiated.
            private OrderMetadata()
            {
            }

            ... (property stubs auto-generated)
        }

        public int NumberOfOrders
        {
            get { return this.Items.Count; }
        }
```

The reason why you cannot do this the way you demonstrated above is because you cannot marshal across anything but conrete classes (anonyous classes are a no-go).  By adding this property to the partial class it will effectively be part of its published signature.